# Assign/call a page inside umbraco template

Tags: templates, master-pages, umbraco

I have a page that has 3 sections... left top, left bottom and Right Column. It uses a masterpage from master template... how would I call three different page to fit in these three sections... For now I harcoded left-top section, but I should be able to edit all these three section from umbraco without having to change any code... basically I created three pages, so that I can insert them to respective sections, but I am not sure how to call them from the templates.

I tried this on all three sections... but it only allows me to edit one section

```
<umbraco:item id="Item1" runat="server" field="bodyText"></umbraco:item>
```

Is there a way, where I can call "mypage" using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this with a master macro which calls the razor scripts with a DynamicNode as param.

```
foreach(DynamicNode child in Model.GetChildrenAsList)
{
     @RenderPage("script name here", new DynamicNode(child.id)) // this lets the next script us Model too
}
```

To get the script name I made a static class that compares the `.NodeTypeAlias` with a list of constants and returns the script path. This way when ever you change something in the tree it will call it differently on load.

You can add as many params as you want in order to play about with the css or structure for example.

Hope this helps.